# How to add SQL Server in networks list?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

After changing my PC name and workgroup, I am no longer able to connect to SQL Server.

Currently in my servers list I have only Home & localhost. Anybody know how to add server to networks list?

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> The network path was not found

Comment: Very common problem. Microsoft even created a special article just for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: What is "my servers list"? Where are you seeing this list? Can you tell us what you see under SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services? Is there a SQL Server instance (running!) and does it say (MSSQLSERVER) or (some other instance name afterward)?